# to Create a bat file to run a query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create a bat file which include a query to run a package.
I use plsql developer to develop the package. its username,password and database is user,pswd,db1 respectively.
The query to run the package is:

```
SELECT        
   COLUMN1 AS "LAST NAME",
   COLUMN2 AS "FIRST NAME",
   COLUMN3 AS "LOCATION"       
FROM TABLE(PKG.GET_SUM('09-NOV-2010','12-NOV-2010'))
```

can anyone help me what code shud I write to create a bat file

Thanks in advance

This is my code

```
connect usr/pswd@db1 
SET NEWPAGE 0 
SET SPACE 0 
SET LINESIZE 80 
SET PAGESIZE 100 
COLUMN COLUMN1 HEADING 'LAST NAME' 
COLUMN COLUMN2 HEADING 'FIRST NAME' 
COLUMN COLUMN3 HEADING 'LOCATION' 
spool c:\temp\get_sums.csv 
SELECT COLUMN1 
    ,COLUMN2 
    ,COLUMN3 
    ,COLUMN4 
    ,COLUMN5 
    , COLUMN6 
    ,COLUMN7,
    COLUMN8 
    ,COLUMN9 
FROM TABLE(ACTY_SUMM('09-NOV-2010','12-NOV-2010')) 
/ 
spool off 
exit;
```

I changed the line size and pagesize. But not able to get the desirable format. I have 12 columns.  I need it in a report format.

Hi I tried to change the Linesize,but still I am not getting the desired format. I want the report in the following format

```
FirstNAME LASTNAME LOCATION  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
NAME1     LNAME1    LOC1     A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1 I1
NAME2     LNAME2    LOC1     A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2 I2
                    LOCTOT   
NAME3     LNAME3    LOC2     A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 H3 I3
                    LOCTOT
```

I need all the column in one row and their corresponding values of each person under each column and after each location there will be location total and at the end there will be grant total. I tried with the linesize,page size and all. still no result. Can anyone help me to get the report in this format

Hi

As of now client is ok with the csv format. But the challenge is I am not getting the heading. This is my code in sql script.

```
connect usr/pwd@db1
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET LINESIZE 100
SET PAGESIZE 0
spool c:\temp\q1.csv

COLUMN COLUMN1 HEADING 'LAST NAME'
COLUMN COLUMN2 HEADING 'FIRST NAME'
COLUMN COLUMN3 HEADING 'LOCATION'
COLUMN COLUMN4 HEADING 'A'
COLUMN COLUMN5 HEADING 'B'
COLUMN COLUMN6 HEADING 'C'
COLUMN COLUMN7 HEADING 'D'
COLUMN COLUMN8 HEADING 'E'
COLUMN COLUMN9 HEADING 'F'
COLUMN COLUMN10 HEADING 'G'
COLUMN COLUMN11 HEADING 'H'
COLUMN COLUMN12 HEADING 'I'
SELECT 
    '"'||COLUMN1
    ||'","'|| COLUMN2 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN3 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN4 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN5 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN6 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN7
    ||'","'|| COLUMN8 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN9 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN10
    ||'","'|| COLUMN11
   ||'","'|| COLUMN12||'"'
FROM
TABLE(ACTY_SUM('09-NOV-2010','12-NOV-2010')) 
/ 

spool off
exit;
```

Can you please suggest on this issue

Comment: Btw you should always use to_date and a format with date literals.  Relying on the default date format is very dangerous, it is frequently different in different clients.

Comment: I am not using date anywhere in the format

Answer (score 3):

First create a script to run the query.  You'll want to capture the output to a file, hence the SPOOL command.

```
connect usr/pswd@db1
spool c:\temp`get_sums.lst

SELECT 

   COLUMN1 AS "LAST NAME",
   COLUMN2 AS "FIRST NAME",
   COLUMN3 AS "LOCATION"

FROM TABLE(PKG.GET_SUM('09-NOV-2010','12-NOV-2010'))
/

spool off
exit;
```

save that to a file called get_sums.sql .  Then you need a batch file get_sums.bat like this:

```
sqlplus /nolog @C:\get_sums.sql
```

There are various SQL*Plus commands you can include in the .sql file t format the output.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a90842/ch7.htm#1005594).

---

Apparently a link to the formatting documentation is not sufficient.

There is no point in setting LINESiZE to 80, that is the default.  If you are selecting nine columns and you want all nine values to appear on one line you need to set the LINESIZE so that it is long enough to accomodate all the columns.  This means you need to set LINESIZE to the sum of all the columns' widths plus eight (the number of interstitial spaces between ninbe columns).

Although I see you have tried

```
SET SPACE 0
```

This causes all the selected columns to run together in one long line, which is a highly unusual way of laying out a report.  But if that's really what you want then ignore the interstitial spaces when calculating the correct value for LINESIZE.

---

Having formatted you posted code I see you are outputting to `.csv`.  Why didn't you say you wanted to export comma separated values in the first place?

There are several ways of doing this.  The most straightforward is to concatenate your query's projection with commas:

```
SELECT 
    '"'||COLUMN1 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN2 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN3 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN4 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN5 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN6 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN7
    ||'","'|| COLUMN8 
    ||'","'|| COLUMN9 ||'"'
FROM TABLE(ACTY_SUMM('09-NOV-2010','12-NOV-2010')) 
/
```

The double-quotes are the optional field terminators, which will handle any string columns which contain commas.

---

> "I dont want coma seperated values. I
>   edited my post. Please suggest "

Here is some test data:

```
SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

♀FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME              LOCATION    A   B   C   D   E   F
--------------------  --------------------  ----------  --  --  --  --  --  --
G   H   I
--  --  --
NAME1                 LNAME1                LOC1        A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1
G1  H1  I1

NAME2                 LNAME2                LOC1        A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2
G2  H2  I2

NAME3                 LNAME3                LOC2        A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3
G3  H3  I3


SQL>
```

I can produce the basic layout you want using SQL*Plus formatting commands

```
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> break on location
SQL> compute count of location on location
SQL> compute count of location on report
SQL> r
  1* select * from t23
♀FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME              LOCATION    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
--------------------  --------------------  ----------  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
NAME1                 LNAME1                LOC1        A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1  H1  I1
NAME2                 LNAME2                            A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2  G2  H2  I2
                                            ----------
                                                     2
NAME3                 LNAME3                LOC2        A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3  G3  H3  I3
                                            ----------
                                                     1

SQL>
```

Comment: +1. Also, remember the CRLF after EXIT. Otherwise it will "hang" (command not sent)

Comment: Hi Is this line like this only "spool c:\temp`get_sums.lst"  or is it like spool c:\temp\get_sums.txt. and CRLF means Can you please explain.thank you

Comment: just add a blank line after exit command. Otherwise EXIT won't get consumed by sqlplus.

Comment: thanks but i got
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "AS"
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "FROM TABLE..." - rest of line ignored.
SELECT
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: remove blank line between SELECT and COLUMN1 as well as between "LOCATION" and FROM

Comment: Hi Thank you all for the wonderful answers..I got the result but I am not getting it as a table format. How can I get this in a table format. My out put is like this
LAST NAME
FIRST NAME
LOCATION
Activity1
LAST NAME
FIRST NAME
LOCATION
Employee1


I want in this format LAST NAME FIRST NAME LOCATION

Comment: Hi I gave csv to check whether I will get the format correctly. I dont want coma seperated values. I edited my post. Please suggest

Comment: Hi I got the values in comma seperated format in the csv file. Thank you for your suggestion APC. But now I am not getting the column  headers. Any way to get that also. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi APC thank you very much for your suggestion. But as of now client is ok with the csv format.But the challenge is I am not able to get the heading. I edited my post and included my code.Can you please suggest me on this issue..Thanks a lot..